# Discrepencies calculating the Content-Digest field

Tags: http-headers, digital-signature

I am attempting to calculate the value for the Content-Digest header off eBay's docs https://developer.ebay.com/develop/guides/digital-signatures-for-apis#sigin

When I try to calculate the example payloads Digest-Header based on how I understand the spec I am getting a different value. Am I understanding the spec wrong or is there a bug in the docs?

> Content-Digest header
>
> NOTE: When no HTTP payload is included (e.g., for a GET call,) this header is not required.
>
> When an HTTP payload is included, this header provides an SHA-256 digest over the HTTP payload.
>
> To add the Content-Digest header (as specified in [draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-10](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-10.html)), calculate an SHA-256 digest over the HTTP payload (in UTF-8 character encoding). While the specification allows adding more than one digest (e.g., both SHA-256 and SHA-512), only the SHA-256 is needed in our case.
>
> Consider the following payload:
>
> `{"hello": "world"}`
>
> In this case, the value of the Content-Digest header will be:
>
> `sha-256=:X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=:`

So based on the spec it appears this header's key is the digest algorithm (in the examples case sha-256) followed by `=`. The value is a base64 encoded digest of the payload encoded in utf-8.

So here is my attempt to calculate the digest in ruby

```
2.5.3 :022 > s = '{"hello": "world"}'.encode('utf-8')
 => "{\"hello\": \"world\"}"
2.5.3 :023 > s
 => "{\"hello\": \"world\"}"
2.5.3 :024 > puts s
{"hello": "world"}
 => nil
2.5.3 :025 > require 'digest'
 => true
2.5.3 :026 > digest = Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest s
 => "5f8f04f6a3a892aaabbddb6cf273894493773960d4a325b105fee46eef4304f1"
2.5.3 :027 > require 'base64'
 => true
2.5.3 :028 > Base64.strict_encode64 digest
 => "NWY4ZjA0ZjZhM2E4OTJhYWFiYmRkYjZjZjI3Mzg5NDQ5Mzc3Mzk2MGQ0YTMyNWIxMDVmZWU0NmVlZjQzMDRmMQ=="
```

As you can see the base 64 encoded digest is nothing like the example.

Comment: Ever figure this out ?

Comment: I did, I answered my own question with what worked for me

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out my issue and will post the solutions here for others. The Content-Digest header (at least for eBays SCA requirements) is a sha-256 hashed utf-8 encoded byte array that is then turned into a base64 encoded string.

```rb
2.5.3 :001 > require 'base64'
 => true
2.5.3 :002 > require 'digest'
 => true
2.5.3 :003 > s = '{"hello": "world"}'.encode('utf-8')
 => "{\"hello\": \"world\"}"
2.5.3 :005 > Digest::SHA256.base64digest s
 => "X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE="
2.5.3 :006 >
```

And I needed this in c# so my implementation looks something like this

```cs
private void _addDigestHeader(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
{
    byte[] hashBytes;
    using (var sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
    {
        hashBytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.InnerXml));
    }
    var hashResult = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

    request.Headers.Add("content-digest", hashResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you mind sharing the other piece of code for 1) Create the signature base,  2) Create the Signature header 3) Create the Signature-Input header

Comment: I got everything at https://github.com/eBay/digital-signature-java-sdk/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ebay/developer/SignatureService.java